# I attached an MSSQL database but its read-only

Tags: sql-server

I copied a small database from one SQL Server 2008 R2 Express (physical) server to another of the same version, but I cannot re-attach. It attaches but the DB is greyed and read-only. It was writable in its former location.

Comment: How large is the db you are re-attaching? In my experience, until the database is "fully attached" it will be shown as read-only so larger database files may take a few moments. Also can you give some more detail on database server types, versions, storage/hardware specs, etc?

Comment: +1 waiting for large files to come online properly is a good tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the SQL Server account has permissions on the folder in which the database file(s) and log file(s) reside.